# Group structure on the Dirichlet binary composition of quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

It is known that the Dirichlet composition of two binary quadratic forms induces an abelian group structure on the set of positive definite quadratic forms with a given discriminant. What is that group structure? Given any two quadratic forms and the Dirichlet composition formulæ, what is the group operation under which it forms an abelian group?

Comment: Dirichlet composition induces a group structure on the set of _equivalence_ _classes_ of binary quadratic forms of a given discriminant. Without passing to equivalence classes, a general form does not have an inverse.

Comment: Dear sir, @JoséCarlosSantos I am reading the notes by Florian Bouyer on composition and bhargava's cubes and also the notes by Franz Lemmermeyer on Binary Quadratic forms. It was said in the former note that the set of primitive binary quadratic forms of discriminant D (denoted as C(D)) is a finite abelian group.

Comment: @AlexB. I am indeed talking about the set of equivalence classes of primitive quadratic lagrange reduced forms. It forms an abelian group. I want to know the identity and the inverse element under the dirichlet composition of 2 quadratic forms.

Comment: It is nonsense even if I said it. You get a group law only on equivalence classes since composition on forms is multivalued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity element is the "principal" form, meaning the form that represents $1.$ This is (the class of) $\langle 1,b,c \rangle,$ same as the class of $\langle c,b,1 \rangle.$ The sameness boils down to the fact that $b$ is divisible by $1.$

Given a form with coefficients $\langle a,b,c \rangle,$ the inverse in the group is $\langle c,b,a \rangle.$ The traditional word for this class is "opposite." Another representative for the opposite class is $\langle a,-b,c \rangle.$

In both cases "form" is taken to mean the $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ equivalence classes.

[image]